# Documentation for derived class in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I would like Doxygen to keep the same documentation for a derived function. However I do not want to leave it empty or repeat the same documentation in the base class. So I will do

In base class:

```
class Base {
   //! does what it's supposed to do
   void Foo();
};
```

In sub-class:

```
class Child : public Foo {

    //! (derived)
    void Foo() override;
}
```

Will Doxygen pick this syntax?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Please give a more complete example so we can also see how `foo` is derived! Did you look into e.g. `\copydoc`?

Comment: Still missing the doxygen version. Did you try the `\copydoc`? Also provide the settings you used in your test that differ from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`).